# mplayer configure Error: libavutil/x86/asm.h header is required for shared FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mplayer

In Ubuntu 14.04,I run `./configure --enable-gui --enable-xvid-lavc --enable-xv --enable-alsa` to install `mplayer`,when it comes to `Checking for FFmpeg ....` then the error shows up. I `cat config.log`, the error details is below:

```
============ Checking for FFmpeg ============

 #include 'libavutil/x86/asm.h'

 int main(void) { return 0; }

cc -Wundef -Wall -Wno-switch -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdisabled-optimization -Wno-pointer-sign -Wdeclaration-after-statement -std=gnu99 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -I. -Iffmpeg -O4 -march=native -mtune=native -pipe -ffast-math -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize /tmp/mplayer-configure--1996/tmp.c -Ilibdvdread4  -fpie -DPIC -D_REENTRANT   -ffast-math -fpie -pie   -lrt -lasound -ldl -lpthread  -lXv  -o /tmp/mplayer-configure--1996/tmp  -lm

In file included from /tmp/mplayer-configure--1996/tmp.c:1:0:

ffmpeg/libavutil/x86/asm.h:30:5: warning: "ARCH_X86_64" is not defined [-Wundef]

 #if ARCH_X86_64

ffmpeg/libavutil/x86/asm.h:50:7: warning: "ARCH_X86_32" is not defined [-Wundef]

 #elif ARCH_X86_32

ffmpeg/libavutil/x86/asm.h:77:5: warning: "ARCH_X86_64" is not defined [-Wundef]

 #if ARCH_X86_64 && defined(PIC)

ffmpeg/libavutil/x86/asm.h:93:5: warning: "HAVE_XMM_CLOBBERS" is not defined [-Wundef]

 #if HAVE_XMM_CLOBBERS

ffmpeg/libavutil/x86/asm.h:105:5: warning: "ARCH_X86_64" is not defined [-Wundef]

 #if ARCH_X86_64 && defined(PIC)

ffmpeg/libavutil/x86/asm.h:111:5: warning: "HAVE_INLINE_ASM_DIRECT_SYMBOL_REFS" is not defined [-Wundef]

 #if HAVE_INLINE_ASM_DIRECT_SYMBOL_REFS

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know what's going on, please Help

Comment: Thank you muru for telling me the true problem. I used to thought it was something wrong with the 'asm.h' file(how stupid i am..). I fixed the dependency like you said and it worked!

Comment: Also I think Sylvain Pineau's method should work too though i didn't try it.

Comment: If you encounter more linker (`ld`) errors, Sylvain's method might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error is:

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
> ```

I think you need to install [`libasound2-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libasound2-dev):

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build `mplayer` from source, I would install all its build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mplayer
```

Answer (score 0):

It would perhaps be easiest to follow this guide on the Ubuntu Forums:

Howto: Build the svn MPlayer under the latest release version of Ubuntu

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2149564

and this would guarantee a working and fully featured copy of MPlayer as well as the most up to date SMPlayer...